# Disabled error ao utilizar junto com formcontrolName: The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date

Tags: angular, typescript

Preciso de um `datepicker` `disabled`, ele possui um `formControlName` pois seu valor é alterado conforme as requisições:

```
<kendo-datepicker disabled formControlName="AgendaData"></kendo-datepicker>
```

O problema é que dessa forma eu recebo um warning no console:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive
>   form directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

Eu tentei fazer no meu form group conforme ele mostra, porém não deu certo.

Eu tentei algo como:

```
  AgendaData: new FormControl({new: new Date(), disabled: true}, [Validators.required]),
```

Porém dessa forma eu tenho:

> The 'value' should be a valid JavaScript Date

Também tentei:

AgendaData: new FormControl({new: new Date(Date.now()), disabled: true}, [Validators.required]),

Comment: tenta tirar o disable do html do seu componente

Comment: Eu já tirei e to tentando tratar no ts, mas tenho os erros do console conforme demonstrado na publicação!

Comment: Tentou assim <kendo-datepicker formControlName="AgendaData"></kendo-datepicker>? mesmo assim da o warning?

Comment: sim, a questão é que eu preciso que ele seja disabled, mas quando eu tento através da construção do formgroup retorna os warnings que coloquei na publicação

Comment: AgendaData: new FormControl({value: new Date(), disabled: true}, [Validators.required]) muda ali de new pra value

Comment: Deu certo, se quiser acrescentar sua resposta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muda ali de new pra value

`AgendaData: new FormControl({value: new Date(), disabled: true}, [Validators.required])`

E retira o disabled do seu html.